# something weird happened while creating wordcloud with python 3

Tags: python, word-cloud

```
def create_wordcloud(sd):
    mask = np.array(Image.open('line.jpg'))
    image_color = wordcloud.ImageColorGenerator(mask)
    word_cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud(background_color='white',
                                     width=1000,
                                     height=1000,
                                     margin=2,
                                     mask=mask,
                                  font_path='simhei.ttf').fit_words(sd)
    plt.imshow(word_cloud.recolor(color_func=image_color))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

    word_cloud.to_file('test1.png')
```

I created a word cloud using python 3, referred to examples from official docs at Github.

At the beginning my code works perfectly, but the problem is when I changed my masking picture('line.jpg') from a colorful one to sketch style using PhotoShop, the code raised an error goes like:

> font_size = int(2 * sizes[0] * sizes[1] / (sizes[0]+ sizes[1]))
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I took a look at the source code and realized that I can simply avoid this error by specifying 'max_font_size' parameter. I did but only to get a void result picture.

I am willing to know how to fix this problem.

ps:
picture 2 is a part of original picture and picture one is the one being reshaped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6luYU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOUcx.png)